# Windows Phone - Application crashes when disconnected from PC

Tags: windows-phone-7

Whenever I disconnect my Windows Phone from PC (connected through USB) and if my application is running, my application hangs for sometime and then application crashes.

Does anyone experienced same behavior? I guess switching for PC connection to Wi-Fi/GPRS is causing the issue.

Comment: Are you debugging your app at the time you disconnect?

Comment: Whether I debug or not. If application is running, it hangs and then crashes. This happens on Samsung Omnia, HTC Trophy and LG-900.

Comment: Are you using data connectivity?

Comment: I guess, if phone is connected to PC, it will always use data connectivity from PC. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Is your application using the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the windows Phone Requires that you Safely Remove hardware first, after a few times when i started Development on the windows phone i did the same and Ended up getting a new Phone. So plainly put, try to Safely Remove and Make sure it is installing the app to the Device.

Meaning if you Remove the phone, the App is still able to be ran just like a normal downloaded App form the Market place.

if you want more in depth information, i would suggest Reading the [WP7 Everything Programming ebook lol](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx)

its filled with good information, and Definitely Helped me along my road to Love DEV for WP7.

Comment: What do you mean by "Safely Remove hardware"?

Comment: Also if your connected to the PC Via USB Most Windows Phones Don't use the Internet from the Computer unless hacked to Compute Network configurations and Pass Packets AKA Tether. So your consistently using your Data connection unless connected to WIFI, Try Connecting to A WIFI connection at least.

Comment: On a Windows Computer you will see a set of icons on the lower right hand side, one being a green arrow with a USB plug right click and safely Remove the Windows Phone.

Comment: In my case, it uses PC data connection without any hack. I am able to access internet without GPRS and Wi-Fi when my phone is connected to PC. I will try to Safely Remove phone and let you know.

Comment: Alright, also if that doesn't work. Try Connecting to Wifi, it would become the main network Protocol and even when connected to PC Wifi would still be connected.

Comment: Great. I will check and let your know.

Comment: How to check whether 3G connection is available using WP7 API?

Comment: If you are plugged into the PC, it will use that connection instead of Wifi ALWAYS. When you disconnect from the PC, it will switch to either cellular or wifi if you have it. You will lose your previous connection. I am not exactly sure why you have to do, but I believe you will have to handle that change. All old tcp connections will get disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

As gamernb says, if you disconnect the USB from a properly tethered Windows Phone (i.e. connected to Zune, or using the WPConnect utility), the phone's network connection will be reset and your app's connections will be terminated. The phone will then start trying to connect using WiFi or cellular data (if they are on), but this can take quite a while.

You will have to handle this network disconnection in your app - I've found that pulling the USB cable in this way is a good ad-hoc test for WP7 apps: do an action which you know will use the network connection. Then watch if the app crashes, or handles this gracefully.

Actually you aren't guaranteed to always use the PC data connection: if you make sure that the computer has no data connection (i.e. pull the Ethernet cable, turn off WiFi etc ), the WP7 app can then use cellular data or WiFi on the phone instead.

Answer (score 0):

Alas-

you could set perimeters in your application to Check what the connection type is, then Make changes accordingly.

You May have a slight freeze, but that's better then a crash....mainly when the phone switches from PC to WWAN, their would be a slight Pause.

use the Reachability Class and NSLog to Figure out whats going on exactly.

I really hope that helps!